# Use regular expressions process string in Android

Tags: java, android, regex, expression

I obtain a response by HttpGet. After getEntity().getContent() I get the code of HTML page, and then convert this page to String pageHTML.

I need to use regular expression match the pageHTML and then obtain the result.

I have created the regular expression.

If regular expression just return a value, how to create?
If regular expression just return n values, how to create?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groups to receive multiple values from a regular expression. See [this](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/regular_expressions/capturing_groups.shtml#.UNLGaqxovlc) for details.

```
Pattern datePatt = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})");

Matcher m = datePatt.matcher(dateStr);
if (m.matches()) {
  int day   = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)); // get values inside the first (..)
  int month = Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)); // get values inside the second (..)
  int year  = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)); // get values inside the third (..)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your regular expressions using a [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). Then you can call `pattern.   matcher(pageHTML)` to get a [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

The `Matcher` allows you to know if there is any `matches`, `find` is there is a next match, and take the `group` representing the last match's sub-sequence.